# Question from an IMC(International mathematics competition) key statge III selection exam

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving, integers

A positive integer n does not have any 9 digits, it has four 8 digits, three 7 digits, two 6 digits and some other digits. If the sum of the digits of the numbeer n is 104 andthe sum of the digits of the number 2*n is 100, find the number of times the digit 5 appears in n.

Guys, my thoughts about the question above, are that in order for the sum of the digits of 2*n to be less than the sum of the digits of n, there have to be many digits inside it, which are larger than or equal to 5. However, this thought, did not lead me to the solution of the problem.

Can you guys please help me complete my thoughts, or, if they are wrong, can you please show me the correct method, of solving, this problem?

Thanking you in advance

Kevin

Comment: Please confirm that the contest is already over. Problems from currently running contests are not allowed. A link to the contest site will do.

Comment: The question is for the internationals, IMC, to select the Cyprus team

Comment: It finished four hours ago

Comment: I am about to send you a link to confirm that what I am saying is true

Comment: https://www.cms.org.cy/news/reminder-for-the-a-selection-competition-for-the-international-mathematics-competition-imc-key-stage-ii-and-key-stage-iii-2019

Comment: what I have just sent, is the reminder, that the Cyprus mathematical society, posted, reminding us of the competition date and time

Comment: RECOMMENDATION FOR THE AWARD SELECTION COMPETITION FOR IMC KEY STAGE II AND KEY STAGE III 2019 INTERNATIONAL COMPETITION
We would like to remind you that all pupils of the E and F grade, and all the students of the A, B and C grade Gymnasium, who were distinguished in the Pancyprian Competitions, held on December 8, 2018, are called to leave the A Selection Competition for the IMC 2019 - Key Stage II and Key Stage III International Competition, which will take place on Wednesday 6 March 2019 at 15:45 - 17:45 at the Pedagogical Institute in Nicosia (P100 Hall) and at the Polemidia Lyceum

Comment: Above, is what the link translates to, from Greek to English

Comment: By the way, I would no have posted the question, had it been an ongoing competition

Comment: Sorry about implying anything. As you are a new user I wasn¨t sure you knew about the rule.

Comment: Please don't use the "logic" tag unless the question is about [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ has digits $d_j$, $j = 0 \ldots m$, then $2n$ has digits $e_j$ where $e_j + 10 c_j = 2 d_j + c_{j-1}$, $c_{j} = 0$ or $1$ being the "carry" from position $j$.
Adding these up for all $j$ tells us $\sum_j e_j + 10 \sum_j c_j = 2 \sum_j d_j + \sum_j c_j$, i.e. $9 \sum_j c_j = 2 \sum_j d_j - \sum_j e_j$.  In your case, that is $2 \cdot 104 - 100 = 108$.  Thus there are $108/9 = 12$ carries.  A carry occurs whenever $d_j = 5, 6, 7, 8$, or $9$.  But you know the number of $6, 7, 8$ and $9$...